# Books/online notes for analytic maps in Banach spaces

Tags: derivatives, reference-request, banach-spaces, analytic-functions, implicit-function-theorem

Can anyone suggest some good books/online notes on (real) analytic maps between Banach spaces? I am looking for the basic definitions and the implicit function theorem in this setting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found to be useful these books

Analytic Theory of Global Bifurcation: An Introduction
Boris Buffoni and John Toland
https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691112985/analytic-theory-of-global-bifurcation

Zeidler, Nonlinear Functional Analysis and its Applications
I: Fixed-Point Theorems
https://link.springer.com/book/9780387909141